# How to compute the points of a CollisionPolygon2D?

Tags: collision-detection, godot, gdscript

`Godot v3.3.1.stable.mono.official`

---

I am trying to draw a CollisionPolygon2D programmatically but I cannot resize or write the `PoolVector2Array` property called `polygon`:

```
extends CollisionPolygon2D


func _ready() -> void:
    polygon.resize(1)
    print(polygon.size())   
    polygon[0] = Vector2.ZERO
```

---

This code prints `0` and throws an error: `Invalid set index '0' (on base: 'PoolVector2Array') with value of type 'Vector2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `PoolVector2Array` is a value type, and reading `polygon` gives you copy. Use another variable to hold it and edit it:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    var points = polygon
    points.resize(1)
    points[0] = Vector2.ZERO
    polygon = points
    print(polygon.size())
```

If you are going to build it over time, I suggest to add another field, and do the modifications to that field:

```
var _points := PoolVector2Array()

func _ready() -> void:
    _points.resize(1)
    _points[0] = Vector2.ZERO
    polygon = _points
    print(polygon.size())
```

And you would be doing `polygon = _points` every time you need to commit the changes.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on what a value type is. I guess `CanvasItem.material` is also a value type? When a property refers to a more complex object than built-in types it gives access to it by a copy? Maybe you can ask and answer a question about that?

Comment: @pietrodito Welcome to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com: [Value/reference type, object and semantics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/408558/45814). An abstract for this case would be that when you get some data, it might be a reference (think a wrapped pointer) to some instance, or it could be the instance. If you get the instance, it is a copy, any modifications on it are not reflected anywhere else. But if it is a reference to the instance, then you manipulating that instance that is stored somewhere else, so the changes are reflected.

Comment: @pietrodito I had a look at Material, and it appears to be a Reference type: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_material.html - It is not really about how complex it is, however the tendency is the opposite. The more complex a type is, the greater the incentive to pass references around instead of copies. However, in some cases GDScript may hide the fact that a copy happens, but not for these array types. I'm not sure how to phase the question (Edit: specific to Godot, of course) to answer that myself.